# Google Maps API v3 - INVALID_REQUEST on Directions request when machine time is 'behind'

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have just stumbled upon an odd issue when making Directions requests through the Google Maps API.

I had a case where requests would always fail on a particular machine, but not on others using the exact same parameters in the Directions request.

By chance, I noticed the machine clock on the fail case was behind my approx 15 mins, so I corrected the time and now the requests are succeeding.

So can anyone shed any light on why this may be the case, e.g. are Google checking extra values passed across in values and rejecting 'old' requests based on extra time info they can sniff out the browser?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, but I would send a bug-report

Comment: Yup. I'd create a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3) too.

Comment: Bug report has now been created - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7952